# Function to round integer or float up to closest increment in Powershell

Tags: function, powershell, rounding

I want to create a function that rounds a number up to the closest increment of five in Powershell. Every number less than 1 should be rounded up to one, but every number greater than 1 should be rounded up to the closes increment of 5 (5, 10, 15 etc.).

I came up with the following function, but was wondering if there's an easier way.

```
Function Get-Increment([float] $value, [int] $increment){
    $value = [math]::Ceiling($value)    
    if($value -gt 1){
        while($value % $increment){$value++}
    }
    return $value
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is more performant ( need to be tested, I've no time now):

```
Function Get-Increment([float] $value, [int] $increment=5){    
    if($value -gt 1)
    {
      [Math]::Ceiling($value / $increment) * $increment;
    }
    else
    {
      [math]::Ceiling($value)    
    }    
}
```

Comment: I did some quick performance tests, and your functions is indeed faster than mine. Not a lot mind, but still there's a noticeable difference when running several times.

Comment: This is great. I got a requirement to increment our minor version to the next 10 values for a normal release and by 1 for a hotfix and this worked amazingly well.